# C++ Letter by letter output

Tags: c++

Is there any way to print words on the same line letter by letter in c++?
Right now, I tried:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
  std::cout << "H";
  system("sleep 0.05");
  std::cout << "e";
  system("sleep 0.05");
  std::cout << "l";
  system("sleep 0.05");
  std::cout << "l";
  system("sleep 0.05");
  std::cout << "o";
  system("sleep 0.05");
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of forking a `sleep` process that will mess up your output, simply use [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for).

Depending on your platform, you might also need to flush the output stream so that it prints to your terminal before the end-of-line:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main() {
  using namespace std::chrono_literals;

  std::cout << "H" << std::flush;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
  std::cout << "e" << std::flush;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
  std::cout << "l" << std::flush;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
  std::cout << "l" << std::flush;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
  std::cout << "o" << std::flush;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
}
```

Alternatively, you can request that all output operations on `std::cout` flush implicitly with `std::unitbuf`:

```
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main() {
  using namespace std::chrono_literals;

  unitbuf(std::cout);
  std::cout << "H";
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
  std::cout << "e";
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
  std::cout << "l";
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
  std::cout << "l";
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
  std::cout << "o";
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);
}
```

Comment: Probably should also `std::flush`.

Comment: That doesn't work for me for some reason :(

Comment: @HolyBlackCat good call!

Comment: Use a loop? `for (char const ch : "Hello") { ... }`

Comment: @Ayxan baby steps! But, yes :)